# Calculate print extent in arcgis from screen extent?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

I am printing with `preserveScale` set to `false` as I need the extent on paper to match what is displayed on screen as closely as possible. Unfortunately the print server does need to fill the paper and takes some liberties here.

So basically I'm currently fighting with ARCGis on trying to calculate what the extent would be that is printed, depending on what is displayed on the screen.
Obviously the aspect ratio of the screens is different as opposed to the one from the print.

Anyone can point my in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because neither your app or the JSAPI inherently know the dimensions of custom print layouts, you'll have to do some math yourself, taking for granted that the print service is going to 'fit' the current map extent

ie: if your print layout is twice as wide as tall, you could interrogate the map extent prior to printing and write custom logic to determine:

- a. whether the ratio between width and height is currently greater or less than 2:1
- b. if greater, you'd divide the current width by 2 to determine the 'height' in the print output
- c. if less, multiply the height by 2 to determine the 'width' of the print output.

Comment: Spending the entire day on the issue I ended up measuring the ARs from the different paper formats we print in (A0 being most common) and matching the map extents to it before printing. Right after the execute call I restore scale and extent. This way I have nearly perfect control over what is on the print, with a little weirdness during but thats ok. 
I still don't like the bad support for printing. The "rectangle positioning on the map" for the client would be very handy to have here. Even a server query to determine physical dimensions would help tremendously.

Comment: since your answer pretty much matches what I discovered so far, that there is no decent way, I'm going to accept it, at least people have some starting point then.